# Can a foul be overriden before it is taken?

Tags: rules, football

Consider the following situation: a player for Team A is ruled offside (or, if you prefer, commits a foul on a Team B player). Before the ensuing indirect free kick can be taken, one of the players of Team B has a moment of madness and blatantly kicks the hell out of a player of Team A. Obviously, the Team B player is going to get a red card, but what happens with the ball? Do Team B get to keep the indirect free kick, or is it overridden with a free kick (or penalty kick, if inside the area) in favor of Team A?

Answer (score 7):

Fouls are called *only* for offences which are committed by a player on the field of play *while the ball is in play*. (See [Interpretations of the Laws of the Game and Guidelines for Referees](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/refereeing/02/36/01/11/27%5f06%5f2014%5fnew--lawsofthegameweben%5fneutral.pdf), page 117.)

If the ball is out of play because the play was stopped by the referee because of a previous offence, no free kick is given, only the persons involved in the misconduct may be cautioned or sent off. So, in your example, the Team B player will be sent off, however, the play will be restarted with the original free kick for Team B.

(Similarly, free kicks are not awarded for misconduct by e.g. a manager, nor for a misconduct of a player outside the field of play. If the referee needs to stop the play because of such misconduct, *no* team will be given a free kick, and the play will be restarted with a dropped ball at the position of the ball at the time the play was stopped.)